# Best way to export React component to image

Tags: reactjs, components, html2canvas

I am creating an app with React and I need to export a react component as image (it is a map). I need the definition of the image to be the highest as possible. What would be the best package to use? I saw html2canvas, DOM-to-Image and Rasterize.

Comment: I am using dom-to-image's `toPng` function for this. You can then set the return value as `src` of an `<image>` and download it from the browser.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.